# Zero sequence number when reading packets from NFQueue

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming, netfilter

I am trying to read the TCP sequence number from a packet that is queued in NFQueue using C++. But when I print out the sequence numbers, I noticed that occasionally I get zero as the sequence number. I checked with Wireshark but there are no sequence numbers that are zero. All the sequence numbers are in order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <netinet/in.h>
extern "C" {
#include <linux/netfilter.h>  /* Defines verdicts (NF_ACCEPT, etc) */
#include <libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
}

using namespace std;

static int Callback(nfq_q_handle *myQueue, struct nfgenmsg *msg,
                nfq_data *pkt, void *cbData) {

    uint32_t id, tSeq;
    unsigned char *pktData;
    nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *header;

    header = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(pkt);
    struct iphdr *iph = ((struct iphdr *) pktData);
    id = ntohl(header->packet_id);

    nfq_get_payload(pkt, &pktData);
    struct tcphdr *tcp = ((struct tcphdr *) (pktData + (iph->ihl << 2)));
    tSeq = ntohl(tcp->seq);

    printf("%u\n", tSeq);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int fd, res;
    char buf[262124];
    struct nfq_handle *nfqHandle;
    struct nfq_q_handle *myQueue;
    struct nfnl_handle *netlinkHandle;

    nfqHandle = nfq_open();
    nfq_unbind_pf(nfqHandle, AF_INET);
    nfq_bind_pf(nfqHandle, AF_INET);

    myQueue = nfq_create_queue(nfqHandle,  0, &Callback, NULL);
    nfq_set_mode(myQueue, NFQNL_COPY_PACKET, 0xffff);

    netlinkHandle = nfq_nfnlh(nfqHandle);
    fd = nfnl_fd(netlinkHandle);

    while(true){
        res = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        nfq_handle_packet(nfqHandle, buf, res);
    }

    nfq_destroy_queue(myQueue);
    nfq_close(nfqHandle);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to retrieve the correct sequence number for other uses. I really want to know the reason behind the zero sequence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Random guess: But could [TCP Offloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine) be influencing what you are seeing?  Have you tried turning it off with `ethtool` or similar setting?

Comment: @selbie Thank you for your reply. I am a student who is learning about networking so I am not sure what TCP offloading is. My professor gave me this project as a challenge. Perhaps you can teach me how to disable TCP offloading while I read up on it? Many thanks for this lead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zero sequence number when reading packets from NFQueue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747314/zero-sequence-number-when-reading-packets-from-nfqueue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just switched the order of two statements in your Callback function.

```
static int Callback(nfq_q_handle *myQueue, struct nfgenmsg *msg,
                nfq_data *pkt, void *cbData) {

    uint32_t id, tSeq;
    unsigned char *pktData = NULL;
    nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *header;

    header = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(pkt);
    nfq_get_payload(pkt, &pktData);
    struct iphdr *iph = ((struct iphdr *) pktData);

    id = ntohl(header->packet_id);
    struct tcphdr *tcp = ((struct tcphdr *) (pktData + (iph->ihl << 2)));
    tSeq = ntohl(tcp->seq);

    printf("%u\n", tSeq);

}
```

The value of `iph` is from `pktData`, but you assigned `pktData` to `iph` before initialize `pktData`, which is probably why your program gets sequence number of 0. I tested on my machine. Let me know if it doesn't works for yours.

Comment: I am using iptables to filter packets into the queue. This is my iptables rule:
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 10.217.131.234 -p tcp --sport 80 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0.
I assume iptables did its job well so I did not check it in my code.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help. I am able to get all the sequence numbers now.